# Sum of one column values from sql database using java?

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

The code seems to show no errors yet when I run it, my ide shows a lang.nullpointerexception. I have no idea what is wrong or how to fix this problem. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Much appreciated.

```
String sql="Select cast(Sum(Copper) as varchar(255)) as sumcu from RawMaterials";
st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=st.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
String sum = rs.getString("sumcu");
sum_text.setText(sum);
```

Comment: Why do you want the sum as a string?  That seems . . . unusual.

Comment: to display it in a text field

Comment: Unrelated, but: why do you retrieve a number as a String. That doesn't make sense

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name... bevause how else do I display it in a text field?